# angular testing directive stub child directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, directive

I want to test a directive whose markup contains a child directive.
e.g.

```
<div class="directiveUnderTest">
  <child-directive></child-directive>
</div>
```

I would like to stub out the child directive in my unit test so it won't try to 'compile' it and instead just ignore this directive.
I could do

```
inject(function($templateCache) {
            $templateCache.put('/path/to/child/directive', '');
});
```

But this now depends on the implementation of the child directive.  I would like to stub out the entire child directive.

I don't want to override the template of the directive under test as I need to compile the real template in order for it to create the expected scope.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because a directive is just a factory, you can mock them out in tests with `$provide`. Then when you build the "fake" directive, you can provide it with a `templateUrl` that will still load what you need. An example below shows a way to make sure the fake directive stays in an isolated scope and provides what you need.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('moduleName', function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('nameOfDirective', function () {
            return { templateUrl: 'path/to/template' };
        }
    });
});
```

Something to be aware of is you actually need to suffix `Directive` onto the name of your directive, the normal compiler will do this automatically when declaring `.directive('name', ...)` to make angular aware of what type of factory it is.